# What Does the Word Animula Mean In Latin

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I just need to know what Animula means in Latin. I’m using it for the name of a kingdom in my book, and Google Translate says that it means Little soul, Piece of soul, and Life. Is that correct? I don’t really trust Google Translate with a dead language like Latin.

Thank you <3

Answer (score 9):

Looks like Google translate was close in this case, though it's wise not to trust it. The word is *anima* plus the diminutive suffix -ula. According to the Lewis and Short dictionary, *animula* is:

> f. dim. [anima], **a little soul, life**: aegra et saucia, Auct. ap. Gell. 19, 11, 4 (Hertz, anima): mulierculae, Sulp. ap. Cic. Fam. 4, 5, 11: vagula, blandula, etc., Hadr. Imp. ap. Spart. Hadr. 25; so Inscr. Orell. 2579 and 4761; Cic. Att. 9, 7.